# 2nd Modalpopupextender in form- CSS link?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an aspx page with an Ajax Modalpopupextender window within a table. The popup is linked to `.ModalBackground` and `.Modalpopup` in my style sheet as instructed which works great.

I now need to add a second Ajax Modalpopupextender window within a table which I have done but don't know how to reference it in the CSS.

I can set a 'Class' in the HTML but not a 'CssClass'. Also, `.Modalpopup` is not referenced in the HTML, it just seems to be a CssClass which Ajax automatically recognises. So how do I set a style for my 2nd Modalpopup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the BackgroundCssClass and BehaviorID of ModalPopupExtender to change Background

If you want to change the Div(Which populate with the ModalPopupExtender) then you can use Style Tags of that Div you are using in Panel.